# Cleaner way to check number of arguments

Tags: java, guava

I want to check the number of arguments passed by the user whether it is within the range of min and max values allowed. What will be the best way to achieve this?

What I have done so far:

```
 if(args.length < min || args.length > max)
      System.out.println("Invalid no. of args");
```

Can it be achieved using some open source libraries like Google Guava or Apache?

Comment: You probably meant || rather than && there - as it stands the message will never be displayed

Comment: @CupawnTae unless max < min ;)

Comment: @fge yes but then the universe would implode, so we wouldn't care ;)

Comment: Not sure if adding an extra dependency for this kind of things is worth when a simple condition does the job.

Comment: Sorry , I just corrected || instead of &&. 
@ZouZou Yes simple condition does this job, but I want to explore more options.

Comment: @ZouZou Guava is always worth it though... When you use it enough, it is even more than a dependency, it becomes an addiction ;)

Comment: I wish we have something using annotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is really cleaner but with Guava you can do this:

```
if (!Range.closed(min, max).contains(args.length))
    // blah blah
```

See the [javadoc for `Range`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v17.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html)

(what is more your initial code is wrong; you want `||`, not `&&`)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to reverse your code. Use **brackets** and **`>= <=`** instead of `> <`.

```
if (args.length >= min && args.length <= max) {
    // Valid no. of args
} else {
    // Invalid no. of args
}
```

Comment: And why would you reverse your code? It is quite the opposite. Checking for an illegal condition allows for an early exit (this is probably a main() here)

Comment: @fge Usually, if data is valid you process them. Hence, `} else {` is easier than _early exit_.

Comment: @Joiner On the other hand, input validation is often composed of more conditions and _early exits_ eliminate to many nested if-else statements.

Comment: @ArturMalinowski @fge I prefer `} else {`, but I am a small developer.

Comment: @Joiner It's always a trade-off :).

Answer (score 0):

Another example with Apache Commons Lang:

```
if (!Range.between(min, max).contains(args.length)) {
    System.out.println("Invalid no. of args");
}
```

[javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/Range.html)